# Warning "downloaded length != reported length" in installing packages from CRAN

Tags: r, warnings, cran, install.packages

Searching on stackoverflow questions, I found out this link:
[Error in file.download when downloading custom file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652001/error-in-file-download-when-downloading-custom-file) .

However, my case is a little bit different (I think):

1) I get this annoying warning when installing some packages from CRAN (or also just some dependencies that get generally installed together with the required package).

2) The downloaded length always appear to be equal to the reported length, so there should be no warning.
As an example, I copy-paste here the warning that has just appeared in updating `mgcv`.

```
Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 1886962 != reported length 1886962
```

The `mode` argument is already set to "wb", so the solution offered in the SO link does not seem to work.

It is very strange, because I have re-installed both R and RStudio recently for other reasons, but this warning has not desappeared.

Any advise is welcome.

Comment: Can you provide the `Sys.info()`?

Comment: `structure(c("Windows", "7 x64", "build 9200", "VAIO", "x86-64", "one-o_000", "one-o_000", "one-o_000"), .Names = c("sysname", "release", "version", "nodename", "machine", "login", "user", "effective_user"))`. Is it normal that I have Windows 8.1 and here the release is 7?

Comment: I had this problem for the first time the other day. Like yours, I got the warnings, in the warning the printed lengths *did* match. The installation seemed to work anyway...

Comment: Same here, and I'm working on win 8 too. here my Sys.info: ` Sys.info()
       sysname        release        version       nodename        machine          login           user effective_user 
     "Windows"        "7 x64"   "build 9200"      "K*****"       "x86-64"    "g*****"    "g******"    "g******"` It too says it's running on 7.

Comment: Got the same. I suspect antivirus or other protection software. I have McAfee and Symantec Endpoint Protection. Is this crossing with you @PavoDive, @DavidePassaretti?

Comment: I have avast but still have also some extensions belonging to McAfee which was by default installed in my windows 8 copy (I just removed the core).

Comment: This sounds like a bug, and [should probably be reported](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/).

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's actually an RStudio bug, as I only encounter that problem when working in RStudio.

Comment: I am having the same issue while trying to install the package 'BH' on my VDI. It seems that the package zip is so large and the network drive is so slow that somehow the the number of bytes are not equal. Any work-around to bypass this error and trust the package?

Comment: You can use R instead of RStudio to install your packages. But now I have no idea about the reason.

Comment: Can help me with this related post please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200536/r-unable-to-install-r-packages-cannot-open-the-connection

Answer (score 9):

### increase the max timeout option beyond the default setting

**Try**: `options(timeout = max(1000, getOption("timeout")))`

This issue is typically caused by trying to download a large file (> 50 MB) that it exceeds the "timeout" option built-into R. The cryptic error message indicates that the amount downloaded is less than the total requested amount, because the request was killed mid-way. From the `?download.file()` docs:

> The timeout for many parts of the transfer can be set by the option timeout which defaults to 60 seconds. This is often insufficient for downloads of large files (50MB or more) and so should be increased when download.file is used in packages to do so. Note that the user can set the default timeout by the environment variable R_DEFAULT_INTERNET_TIMEOUT in recent versions of R, so to ensure that this is not decreased packages should use something like
>
> ```
> options(timeout = max(300, getOption("timeout")))
> ```

Comment: thanks this solved a similar problem for me, though for me the reported and downloaded sizes were not identical.

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered the same problems on windows or linux server. I believed that this is probably caused by the network speed. I tried to install this package for the second or even the third time (using the function install.packages) or manually download the desired package from CRAN and then installed it and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I  solved my problem by going to this [site](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/) and downloading the required package. The problem of different lengths was due to the inability to download the folder completely from R so I did download it directly and call it from the install button in Packages and selecting zip file rather than CRAN. Then just select the folder and that was for me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For reference:

I am running Windows Vista, and am getting the same error for various package installs (where the download size is reported to not equal the reported length despite the numbers displayed being equal). The packages appear to install correctly, despite the reported error.

RStudio version 0.98.1091

> SysInfo()

```
release                                                 Vista x64
version                                build 6002, Service Pack 2
```

> version

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
```

My guess (without any knowledge of the internals of the `install.packages` code) is that while integers are being reported, they are not being compared as integers, and so throwing the error.

Comment: I would have made it a comment, but I can't comment on the OP. I was just adding some data.

Comment: You should be able to get enough points to comment by viewing the help page and voting once or twice or something along those lines.

Comment: this is not an answer at all

Comment: Commenting requires 50 reputation

Answer (score 0):

After reading that this was happening because of a [time out during downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68944877/5783745), I switched to a faster internet connection and everything immediately worked as expected.