# Download all available data with getSymbols

Tags: r, warnings, quantmod

I'd like to download the full history of data from Yahoo Finance for several stocks, but I always only get data starting at 2007-01-03. For example:

```
> library(quantmod)
> e <- new.env() 
> getSymbols( "MSFT", src="yahoo", env=e)
[1] "MSFT"
Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  downloaded length 137552 != reported length 200
> e$MSFT[1,]
#            MSFT.Open MSFT.High MSFT.Low MSFT.Close MSFT.Volume MSFT.Adjusted
# 2007-01-03     29.91     30.25     29.4      29.86    76935100      24.28526
```

I searched stackoverflow questions about the "downloaded length != reported length" warning and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583767/warning-downloaded-length-reported-length-in-installing-packages-from-cran), but the solutions there do not solve the problem.

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I don't get the full downloaded file. My dates do not go further back than 2007, but in reality it should. The examples given in the "quantmod" website shows the dates should go further back and I know MSFT's data should.

Comment: The default for `from` is `"2007-01-01"`. If you want more data, change the value of `from`.

Comment: ohh! I didn't know the default was stuck at 2007. Now, every company has a different "from" date, is there a way to set "from" to go as far back as possible? Or should I just do a for-loop?

Comment: Just make it something silly, like `"1900-01-01"`.

Comment: Thank you so much! People like you make a difference to the world :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the default for `from` is `"2007-01-01"` for `getSymbols.yahoo` (and many of the other `getSymbols` functions).  If you want all the available history, set `from = "1900-01-01"`.

```
R> getSymbols("MSFT", from="1900-01-01")
# [1] "MSFT"
R> MSFT[1,]
#            MSFT.Open MSFT.High MSFT.Low MSFT.Close MSFT.Volume MSFT.Adjusted
# 1986-03-13  25.49952  29.24928 25.49952   27.99936  1031788800      0.068281
```

Comment: Can I use this function to extract gold and silver price?

Comment: @user2733617: yes, see `?getMetals`.

Comment: getMetals( "XAU", from="1980-01-01")

[1] "XAUUSD"
Warning message:
In getSymbols.oanda(Symbols = metals, from = from, to = to, auto.assign = auto.assign,  :
  Oanda limits data to 5years. Symbol: XAU/USD

Comment: why am I being limited to 5 years?

Comment: Because that's what Oanda (the data provider) does.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a way where I can get all the opening and closing prices for metals beyond just 5 years?

Comment: No, I don't know where you can get that for free.